# Can't insert multiple objects from a JSON file into my MongoDB, it only inserts the first one

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, mongoose

I made a script which inserts all the objects from a JSON file into my DB collection, and a script that deletes everything from the same collection. The delete one works fine, however, the insert one only inserts the first object of the JSON file. I've required FS, I've parsed the file as JSON, hell, it inserts the first one properly. Also checked my JSON file, no problems with it, all the curly brackets and commas are where they're supposed to be. The error, for some reason, is undefined? Any help is greatly aprreciated.

```
//IMPORT DATA INTO DATABASE
const importData = async () => {
  try {
    await Tour.create(tours);
    console.log('Data successfully loaded!');
  } catch {
    console.log(err);
  }
  process.exit();
};

//DELETE ALL DATA FROM COLLECTION
const deleteData = async () => {
  try {
    await Tour.deleteMany();
    console.log('Data successfully deleted!');
  } catch {
    console.log('Error!');
  }
  process.exit(); 
};
```

Comment: The sample code doesn't show reading from a file?

Comment: @Joe I just uploaded a snippet, I thought uploading an entire file was unwelcome on Stack Overflow. Here's the entire file for anyone that cares

https://pastebin.com/Sf9A5xs5

Comment: Please try printing the `tours` variable to check if it has array of objects.

Comment: __the error is for some reason undefined__. Specify an identifier for the catch block e.g. `catch(e)`, log that and share the output of the log`.

Comment: @codetiger Yup, console log shows all the tours I have.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule I've done that by trying console.log(err), however it says that's depreciated?

Answer (score 0):

I actually got it to work. Rewrote the import script into an if else, and the error showed "duplicate indexes/keys" in my DB. So I simply ran db.collection.dropIndexes() before importing, and it works great now!